# Why node nc (netcat) give error "inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host"?

Tags: unix, netcat

`nc` works fine when i execute it on a VM.

```
Connection to 10.0.0.10 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
```

But when I execute the same command inside my docker container, it gives the below UNKNOWN error/exception.

```
10.0.0.10: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host 
(UNKNOWN) [10.0.0.10] 22 (ssh) open
```

Below is the `nc` command that I am using:

```
nc -vz 10.0.0.10 22 -w 4
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

"Inverse host lookup failed" simply means that `nc` wanted to print which host name 10.0.0.10 corresponds to, but couldn't.

UNKNOWN is simply what it then prints as the host name.

This is distinct from "I looked it up, but it doesn't seem to correspond to anything" which is what happens outside the container.

To be perfectly explicit, connecting to the host succeeded, but looking up its name from the IP address failed. This is just an informational warning message, not a hard error; the lookup is entirely optional, anyway, and can be disabled with `-n`.

If you really want to avoid this warning and not switch to `-n`, you need to set up working DNS inside the container.

Comment: so, with this exception "inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host", can we assume that connection is succeeded..!? Because my intention is to do SSH test.

Comment: The reverse lookup is purely for human friendly output, and has no bearing on whether or not the requested operation is successful (unless you happen to be testing for working DNS).

Comment: @Rohith so , in the end, does this "open" part mean that the connection is succeeded? Because this is confusing me too...

Comment: @GileBrt See updated answer now. The connection succeeded.

Answer (score 11):

Simply provide the `-n` option on both sides of listener and client to remove this error as it will neglect the DNS look up by using it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is expected if you have **not** SSH'ed into the docker container.

`Connection to 10.0.0.10 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!` is seen in the VM because you have SSH'ed into the VM as `ssh username@10.0.0.10` and port `22` is used in the VM for SSH.

But, when you are inside a docker container (using `docker run` or `docker exec` or `docker attach`), port `22` will **not** be used, and hence the following error from `nc` is expected inside the docker container:

```
10.0.0.10: inverse host lookup failed: Unknown host 
(UNKNOWN) [10.0.0.10] 22 (ssh) open
```

Here are the steps to successfully test if port `80` is used using `nc` inside an `nginx` docker container:

```
$ sudo docker run --name docker-nginx -d -p 80:80 nginx
$ sudo docker exec -it docker-nginx /bin/bash
root@60ec582e90f4:/# apt-get -y update
root@60ec582e90f4:/# apt-get -y upgrade
root@60ec582e90f4:/# apt-get install -y net-tools
root@60ec582e90f4:/# apt-get install -y netcat   

# make sure that port 80 is used
root@60ec582e90f4:/# netstat -pan | grep 80
tcp     0   0 0.0.0.0:80   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  1/nginx: master pro 

# nc will work now inside the nginx container as port 80 is used inside the container

root@60ec582e90f4:/# nc -vz 127.0.0.1 80 -w 4
localhost [127.0.0.1] 80 (?) open
```

Hence, for `nc -vz a.b.c.d P -w 4` to work inside a container, port `P` must be used on IP address `a.b.c.d` inside that container.